# Uncountable nouns and demonstratives

Tags: nouns

Do we use all demonstratives (**this, that, these, those**) with

1. uncountable nouns? (information, advice etc.)
2. nouns which have just plural form?  (trousers, eyeglasses, etc.)
3. nouns which have just singular form? (I forgot.)

Can you write me some examples and some internet sources?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Singulars "this" and "that" with singular-only non-count nouns (e.g. _this/that information/harm/furniture/crockery/nonsense_), Plurals "these and those" with plural-only non-count nouns (e.g. _these/those scissors/trousers/clothes/cattle/police_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uncountable nouns

Uncountable nouns are referred to as though they were singular, so you can say **this information** or **that information** but not *these information* or *those information*, because *these* and *those* are only for plural things.

2. [*plurale tantum*](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/12-nouns-that-are-always-plurals/)

Because these are always plural, you have to refer to them with the plural forms, **these** and **those**: **these trousers** or **those trousers**, not *this trousers* or *that trousers*.

3. Singular-only nouns

There are very few words in English that are really singular-only.  Most of the ones that look singular-only either have the same form in both singular and plural, or they function more like mass nouns.  The best example I can think of right now is [*news*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/news), which Merriam-Webster calls "plural in form but singular in construction".  [It's almost always used as a singular: **this news** or **that news**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20news%2Cthat%20news%2Cthese%20news%2Cthose%20news&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20news%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20news%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20news%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthose%20news%3B%2Cc0)